# Deriving the equation of an ellipse from another related equation

Tags: conic-sections

Consider the equation for $x,y, \phi \in \mathbb{R}$
$$ \left( \frac{x}{a} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{y}{b} \right)^2 - 2 \cos (\phi) \frac{xy}{ab} = \sin^2 (\phi) $$
It is supposed to be an elementary exercise to show that the vector $(x,y)$ traces out an ellipse, but I am not quite seeing it. If I attempt to solve for some constant $A,B,C,D,R \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ \frac{(x - A)^2}{B} + \frac{(y - C)^2}{D} = R^2$$
would match the above equation, then I always end up with the non-linear term $xy$ causing me problems. On the other hand with
$$ \frac{(x - Ay)^2}{B} + \frac{(y - Cx)^2}{D} = R^2$$
We have
$$ x^2 \left( \frac{1}{B} + \frac{C^2}{D} \right) - 2 xy \left( \frac{ A}{B} + \frac{C}{D}\right) + y^2 \left( \frac{A^2}{B} + \frac{1}{D}\right) = R^2$$
Now we would have
$$ \frac{1}{a^2} = \frac{1}{B} + \frac{C^2}{D}$$
$$ \frac{1}{b^2} = \frac{1}{D} + \frac{A^2}{B}$$
$$ \frac{\cos (\phi)}{ab} = \frac{A}{B} + \frac{C}{D}$$
$$ \sin^2 \phi = R^2$$
However now the equation of the ellipse is in the wrong "base". Any ideas?

Comment: This seems like a standard ellipse represented in a coordinate system rotated by $\phi$ . Try the transformations $x \mapsto x \cos \phi - y \sin \phi$ and $y \mapsto x \sin \phi + y \cos \phi$.

Comment: What do you mean the wrong "base"? Also, notice that by symmetry, we can write the foci as $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(-x_0, -y_0)$.

Comment: The term "base" here refers to the fact that I want to uniquely identify the ellipse with the equation of an ellipse centered at the point $(a,b)$. The second equation is not, but I think @vnd is right and the ellipse I am considering is rotated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

The $xy$ term is not nonlinear, it has the effect of tilting the principal axes.

Like e.g., in: [ $ x^2 - xy + y^2 = 1 $] .

$ \phi = \pi/2 $ is ellipse standard form.

Comment: Yes, I figured this out from the comments as well. The exercise I was doing was unclear as to the orientation of the ellipse I had to derive, I had not considered rotations!